# Method to persist state of expansion of nested properties in property manager?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently using ExpandableObjectConverter in a custom control (vb.net) that I've written. I'm able to 'nest' properties which are visible to the vs.net Properties Windows of the vs.net UI. After manually expanding the 'MyProperties_Parent' item with the mouse, this allows me to see and set variable that look like this:

Appearance      <- This is my Category
....-MyProperties_Parent  <-The 'base' of my properties class, after I 'expand' it.
........MyVar1    A
........MyVar2    B
........MyVar3    C

However, if I leave the control and switch to another in the vs.net designer, then click back on the my control, the 'MyProperties_Parent' property is now collapsed, i.e....

Appearance     <-This is my Category
....+MyProperties_Parent    <-The 'base' of my properties class, now closed by default.

Is it possible for me to have my base (MyProperties_Parent) either remember it's last used state, or default to being 'expanded' to prevent having to expand it with the mouse every time I visit that property in the Properties Window of the UI? Perhaps this is an Attribute with which I can decorate the Property?